# HTML does not maintain formatting after using docx4j XHTMLImporterImpl

Tags: java, docx4j

Im currently using XHTMLImporterImpl version 8.0 and docx4j 8.23

I have the current html, saving this to a file and viewing in a browser looks good but after using the conversion, we loose all formatting...any ideas??

```html
<html>
<div>
    <div id="divHfBody" style="display:table;border-collapse: collapse;">
        <div id="divHfBody" style="display:table-row;">
            <div id="divHfBody" style="display:table-cell;border: 1px solid #000000;width:5%;padding:3px;">CODE1</div>
            <div id="divHfBody" style="display:table-cell;border: 1px solid #000000;width:80%;padding:3px;">DESC1</div>
            <div id="divHfBody" style="display:table-cell;border: 1px solid #000000;width:10%;padding:3px;">1.234</div>
        </div>
        <div id="divHfBody" style="display:table-row;">
            <div id="divHfBody" style="display:table-cell;border: 1px solid #000000;width:5%;padding:3px;">CODE2</div>
            <div id="divHfBody" style="display:table-cell;border: 1px solid #000000;width:85%;padding:3px;">DESC 2</div>
            <div id="divHfBody" style="display:table-cell;border: 1px solid #000000;width:10%;padding:3px;">2.0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

I then make the following call, but when I look at the word document that is produced after the save, I do not see the same format as in a browser.  I only see a box on the other div.  all divs shows as a new row..similar to the following

```bash
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    -CODE1                                                      -
    -DESC1                                                      -
    -1.234                                                      -
    -CODE2                                                      -
    -DESC2                                                      -
    -2.0                                                        -
    -------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my conversion code

```java
XHTMLImporterImpl importer = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);
List<Object> pHtml = importer.convert(divHtml, null);
```

Comment: I guess the code which recognises table elements has some dependency on node names, not just CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html displays a table, because you use the css styles `display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` to tell the browser to render your html as a table. However, docx4j has limits when it comes to interpreting css styles.

If you would use html tags instead of css styles to display the table, the conversion would work. In that case, the html you would feed to the docx4j importer would have to look similar to this:

```
<div>
    <table id="divHfBody" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr id="divHfBody">
            <td id="divHfBody" style="border: 1px solid #000000;width:5%;padding:3px;">CODE1</td>
            <td id="divHfBody" style="border: 1px solid #000000;width:80%;padding:3px;">DESC1</td>
            <td id="divHfBody" style="border: 1px solid #000000;width:10%;padding:3px;">1.234</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="divHfBody">
            <td id="divHfBody" style="border: 1px solid #000000;width:5%;padding:3px;">CODE2</td>
            <td id="divHfBody" style="border: 1px solid #000000;width:85%;padding:3px;">DESC 2</td>
            <td id="divHfBody" style="border: 1px solid #000000;width:10%;padding:3px;">2.0</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid the html table because I ran into an issue when I take html that has many tables and try to add it to a table in the word document.  i.e  In the word document I have a bookmark that is in a cell of a table, then I have to replace the bookmark with html that has many nested table.  Docx4j seems to throw conversion errors when i try to do that, so i was working with span or div elements with borders, but can seem to get the borders to print for each cell using the span or div elements.